# Change an Azure DevOps project to use an inherited process

Tags: azure-devops

Can I change an Azure DevOps project to use an inherited process?

**Background:**

I created an Azure DevOps project, and then later realized that the default `Agile` process doesn't have the `work item types` that I needed. Based on this hint in the UI:

```
System processes cannot be customized. To add customization create an inherited process.
```

I created an inherited process (let's call it `Agile++`).

Naturally the next step is to change the project to use `Agile++` instead of `Agile`... but lo and behold, I can't seem to change the process associated with the project.

Am I overlooking something really simple? See screenshot below:

[image: can't change process screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change an Azure DevOps project to use an inherited process

First, you should make sure you have permission to change the process of team project.

Go to `Project Settings`->`Security`->`Change process of team project.`:

[image]

Then, go to `Organization Settings`->`Process`, select the inherited process `Agile++` and `select Change team projects to use Agile++` from the drop down menu on the right:

[image]

And select the project, which you want to change, click OK button.

[image]

If you follow above steps, and it still not work for you, please send me much more info abut the problem you got, I will keep follow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked ... although it's much more convoluted than it needs to be. Thank you!

Comment: I have permissions but I don't see the “Change team projects to MyProcess”  option :(

Answer (score 1):

Leo Liu-MSFT's answer is no longer accurate in Azure DevOps. Now you need to go to the existing process (under Org settings) and choose the 'Projects' tab. Find the project to want to change the process of and click the ... -> 'Change process' -> select the new inherited process.

Comment: Spot on correct as of Jan 2022